# building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '.../GoogleMaps' for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, applet, apple-m1

building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/wahab/Documents/Github/ios-code/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps' for architecture arm64

I found this error while compiling my swift code in macbook pro M1. Please help me on this regards Thanks

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Please follow these points:
Close Xcode -->
-->Go to Finder
-->Then Click Application
-->Then Right-click on the "Xcode"
-->Then You will see "Get Info"
-->Then Check marked the "Open using Rosetta"

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow These steps:

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to Finder[image]
3. Then Click Application
4. Then Right-click on the "Xcode"
5. Then You will see "Get Info"
6. Then Check marked the "Open using Rosetta"

Answer (score 1):

The Maps SDK for iOS does not yet contain the architecture necessary to run on the new Arm-based Mac Simulators. For now, if you are using the new Arm-based Macs, you will need to develop using a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my Mac Book as well. I updated my Mac OS to latest version which is Monterey version 12.4. After updating my Mac OS, the first time when I opened my Xcode, a pop up to install the debugging tools appeared. After the installing the debugging tools in the Xcode, I was able to run the iOS application with google maps framework in my simulator. Hope it helps.

Note:
I did try changing the architectures but it's of no use.

Answer (score -1):

Build your app in iOS 13.0 Simulator.